# "Pack the/your neck" meaning?

Tags: meaning

[Video](http://youtu.be/7P78Pzu-mFc?t=11s)

In the video, I see the guy just draw his neck a bit backward and make it align/perpendicular with his back. Is it what the term **"Pack the/your neck"** simply mean?

**Edit**: Added more context for guys who cannot see the video

Comment: Probably it's a jargon used by body builders which (with a high possibility) means trying to pull your head between your shoulders and putting your head 90 degree fixed position to your shoulders which should create a straight line with your back. (**Note:** I am not sure about it.)

Comment: You may wish to copy the sentence (along with its surrounding context) into your question. Not everyone wants to (or is able to) go watch a video for something that can easily be represented as text. Make it easy on the people who give answers and you make it more likely that you'll get a good answer!

Comment: I thought the phrase is a commonplace for native speak - turned out it isn't- so i didn't intend to put in more context, and i just provide the video link just for the extra reference of where i get the phrase.

Answer (score 2):

When you pack a suitcase, you often compress the items within it to get them to fit into a smaller space. In this case, I believe that "pack" means "shorten" or "compress" in this same sense, although of course you cannot really compress a neck in the same way that you compress clothes.